What was the value addition of Moses' speech deficiency to his leadership?
We read in Ex 4:10-15 (KJV):

And Moses said unto the Lord, O my Lord, I am not eloquent, neither heretofore, nor since thou hast spoken unto thy servant: but I am slow of speech, and of a slow tongue.
And the Lord said unto him, Who hath made man's mouth? or who maketh the dumb, or deaf, or the seeing, or the blind? have not I the Lord?
Now therefore go, and I will be with thy mouth, and teach thee what thou shalt say.And he said, O my Lord, send, I pray thee, by the hand of him whom thou wilt send.
And the anger of the Lord was kindled against Moses, and he said, Is not Aaron the Levite thy brother? I know that he can speak well. And also, behold, he cometh forth to meet thee: and when he seeth thee, he will be glad in his heart.
And thou shalt speak unto him, and put words in his mouth: and I will be with thy mouth, and with his mouth, and will teach you what ye shall do.

Later we see Aaron always  accompanying Moses except on a few occasions like the receipt of the Commandments.  God could have easily removed Moses' deficiency on Day One, but ordained that it stays. The fact that Moses was instrumental in the successful redemption of Israel from Egypt proves that his speech deficiency did help him.
My question is: What was the value addition made by Moses' speech deficiency to his leadership?

I fear the answer to this question might come under the category of "opinion based" - although I might be wrong!  The Bible might have something to say about benefits from God's prophets having a speech impediment. My guess is it made Moses humble, but that's only an opinion.

Thanks, Lesley. Moses is not at first  convinced of his abilities and the support of God . He complains in Ex 6 : to But Moses said to the Lord, “If the Israelites will not listen to me, why would Pharaoh listen to me, since I speak with faltering lips?” . We then see him metamorphosing into a strong personality , realising that God is his only strength.

I would suggest that his inability to speak eloquently was another way for God to humble those who were seen as "better" than Himself or His chosen.

But God hath chosen the foolish things of the world to confound the wise; and God hath chosen the weak things of the world to confound the things which are mighty; (1 Corinthians 1:27)

As your own verse in your question points out... It's okay if I am weak, insecure, ill-equipped and inadequate as long as I am humble, teachable, obedient, and surrender myself to God's will for me.

I have some different views on the topic. Researchers say that stammering can either be inborn or acquired. There is no mention in OT that Moses was deficient of speech before he killed the Egyptian ( Ex 2) and fled for life.  He may have developed the characteristic out of the post- murder trauma. Though he returned to Egypt after many years, he knew he was still ' wanted dead or alive' in Egypt. The stammering, a quality generally attributed to persons of weak mind, in deed helped Moses in disguising himself before the Pharaoh.

If you already had an answer that was based on science, are you asking so you can have a theological answer? I only answered a theological way, because I assumed you were asking for a spiritual/theological answer.

Thanks, Wyrsa. My inputs are based on sheer circumstantial leads. For instance, Moses does not tell God that he had murdered an Egyptian and was better off not going back. In Ex 2 he reprimands the Hebrews who were fighting each other. He may have stayed away, if he was speech deficient. Hence my theory that he developed stammering at a later stage. Not necessary it was a conscious move .

I'm not disagreeing with your conclusions. :) Just pointing out that I understood it as a theological one. Hence my "God humbles the powerful through the weak" He probably wasn't well accepted by the hebrews either when he returned. I'm sure they performed some kind of massive group punishment for what Moses did.

Wyrsa, I personally do not see Moses as a role model of humility. In Ex 20:11 he strikes the rock for water as against God's instruction to speak to it. And he pays for the disobedience, by not being able to step on the Promised Land.

I didn't say he was a role model of humility. I said God humbled the Pharaoh through him. :-)

Yes Wyrsa, you are right.


The fact that Moses was instrumental in the successful redemption of Israel from Egypt proves that his speech deficiency did help him.

I actually think that what this proves is that human ability or disability has nothing whatsoever to do with spiritual success.  Moses' speech deficiency did not hinder God in using Moses.

But God hath chosen the foolish things of the world to confound the wise; and God hath chosen the weak things of the world to confound the things which are mighty; And base things of the world, and things which are despised, hath God chosen, yea, and things which are not, to bring to nought things that are: That no flesh should glory in his presence. - 1 Corinthians 1:27-29

Just consider Gideon.  He had 32,000 men with him.  God whittled that down to 300 men and the reason given was:

And the LORD said unto Gideon, The people that are with thee are too many for me to give the Midianites into their hands, lest Israel vaunt themselves against me, saying, Mine own hand hath saved me. - Judges 7:2

If Moses' deficit provided him any benefit I think it was that recognized deficiencies make us prone to humility, which thing God has promised to give grace unto.

Thanks, Mike Borden. Judges 7:2 is the Quote of the Day !
